# Optimizacion de una matriz de 570x512 en GUI

Tags: python, matriz, datos

tengo el siguiente problema .... necesito crear una matriz de 570x512 en la interfaz grafica tkinter. Cree la matriz con un arreglo de For pero el inconveniente da cuando lo ejecuto, se demora demasiado en crear la matriz con el tamaño asignado. Lo que busco es crear una matriz para introducir un dato binario de luz o oscuridad, nose si se puede trabajar con pixeles en una matriz para generar una especie de ionograma(una especie de foto con ondas). Agradezco cualquier comentario o sugerencia.

Adjunto la foto de un ionograma, es a lo que tengo que llegar a programar...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont  # libreria



raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Ionograma")  # nombre de la ventana
raiz.geometry("1550x850")  # tamaño de la ventana
raiz.config(bg="#0A0A1A")  # colro del fondo

letra_t = tkFont.Font(family="Italic ", size=30)  # tipos de letras y tamaños d
letra_b = tkFont.Font(family="Italic ", size=10)

ionograma = Label(raiz, text="Ionopro", font=letra_t)  #
ionograma.grid(row=200, column=100, )  # posicion del titulo
ionograma.config(bg="#0A0A1A", fg="#FFFFFF")  # color de fondo y color de letra



botonera= Frame (raiz)                                            #margenes botonera
botonera.config(bg="white")
botonera.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.08,relwidth=0.09, relheight=0.7)

#BOTONES
boton = Button(botonera, text="SCAM",font=letra_b,height=4, width=17)
boton.pack()

boton2 = Button(botonera, text="Mediciones",font=letra_b,height=3, width=17)
boton2.pack()

boton3 = Button(botonera, text="Informacion",font=letra_b,height=3, width=17)
boton3.pack()

contenedor = Frame(raiz)                                           #margenes donde va ir la matriz
contenedor.config(bg="white")
contenedor.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.8, relheight =0.8)


iono = []
col=40  #570
fil=20  #512

ncol=1/col
nfil=1/fil

for i in range(int(fil)):           #matriz
    iono.append([])
    for j in range(int(col)):
        iono[i].append(LabelFrame(contenedor))
        iono[i][j].config(borderwidth=0.5)
        iono[i][j].place(relx=ncol*j, rely=nfil*i,
                         relwidth=ncol, relheight =nfil)


raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, has hecho una buena primer pregunta de forma clara y con la información necesaria, aún así, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). De esa forma podrás ganar tu primer medalla.

Comment: Estuve haciendo pruebas con tu código, por lo que vi, el problema no es en el tiempo que tarda en fabricarse la matriz (Para 570x512 tardó 5 segundos en mi computadora) pero el mostrar todo en la pantalla es muy tardado (La verdad no esperé a que terminara ya que pasaron 5 minutos y no pasaba nada), entonces el problema no está en sí en fabricar la matriz, sino en renderizar todo en tkinter, ¿Es correcto?

Comment: hola, al parecer si, pero me surge la duda esa es mejor manera de representar una imagen en una matriz, estuve investigando y también se podria hacerlo con un arreglo de tuplas para indica la imagen final.

Comment: Estoy redactando una respuesta con una forma relativamente sencilla de dibujar pixel por pixel que te permitirá cargar la imagen en menos de un segundo, pero como no tengo los datos del Ionograma estoy haciendo una imagen sencilla para ejemplificar el proceso

Comment: wow muchas gracias, talvez ofreces servicios de freeelancer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hice pruebas con tu código agregando el módulo `time` para ver cuanto se tarda en generar la matriz, el cambio que hice es de la siguiente manera:

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(int(fil)):           #matriz
    iono.append([])
    for j in range(int(col)):
        iono[i].append(LabelFrame(contenedor))
        iono[i][j].config(borderwidth=0.5)
        iono[i][j].place(relx=ncol*j, rely=nfil*i,
                         relwidth=ncol, relheight =nfil)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.perf_counter() - start_time))
```

Si configuro `col=570` y `fil=512` el tiempo que tarda en mi computadora es:

```
--- 5.607332199986558 seconds ---
```

Por lo que el problema no está en crear la matriz, sino en renderizar todo en `tkinter`

Tal como sugeriste en tu pregunta, una forma de hacerlo sería "dibujar" pixel por pixel, no hay una forma directa de hacerlo así que se podría hacer con un `canvas` y crear un `string` con la información de cada pixel

En tu código tienes un contenedor "flexible" que se puede reemplazar por el canvas, pero la imagen que se va a mostrar no es flexible así que tenemos que definir un tamaño y creamos el canvas

```
#Tamaño de la imagen
x = 1240
y = 680

#Crear canvas
canvas = Canvas(raiz, width = x, height = y, bg = "#ffffff")
canvas.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.8)
```

Luego creamos la imagen con el tamaño deseado

```
#Crear imagen
img = PhotoImage(width = x, height = y)
canvas.create_image((0, 0), image = img, state = "normal", anchor = NW)
```

Para renderizar la imagen vamos a utilizar el método `put()`, y la variable que nombre `ionograma` va a contener la información de cada pixel

```
#Poner la imagen
img.put(ionograma)
```

La forma de "escribir" ese `string` con la información de cada pixel tiene que cumplir con las siguientes "reglas"

1. Cada "fila" de información debe ir entre llaves `{}`
2. Todo debe ser un único `string`
3. Cada pixel debe tener formato "#RRGGBB"

Por ejemplo, si tuviéramos una imagen de 10 pixeles de ancho por 5 de alto (Ya sé que es muy pequeña pero es para ejemplificar) entonces el `string` tendría que ser (Dibujando algunos pixeles rojos = #ff0000 y otros azules = #0000ff):

```
'{ #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff} { #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff} { #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff} { #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff} { #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #ff0000  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff  #0000ff}'
```

Debes notar que cada 10 pixeles se cierran las llaves para marcar el fin de la fila, si cuentas cada uno vas a ver que hay en total 50 pixeles.

Como no tengo la información del infograma estoy creando una imagen muy sencilla, únicamente mostrando líneas verticales y horizontales cada N = 310 y M = 170 pixeles:

```
#Imagen de prueba, dibujará cada pixel del tamaño x, y. si el pixel es múltiplo de 310 en "x" o de 170 en "y" lo pondrá en rojo , de lo contrario en azul
ionograma = ' '.join('{' + ' '.join(' #ff0000' if ((i%310==0) or (j%170==0)) else ' #0000ff' for i in range(x)) + '}' for j in range(y))
```

Juntando todo lo anterior:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont  # libreria
import time



raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Ionograma")  # nombre de la ventana
raiz.geometry("1550x850")  # tamaño de la ventana
raiz.config(bg="#0A0A1A")  # colro del fondo

letra_t = tkFont.Font(family="Italic ", size=30)  # tipos de letras y tamaños d
letra_b = tkFont.Font(family="Italic ", size=10)

ionograma = Label(raiz, text="Ionopro", font=letra_t)  #
ionograma.grid(row=200, column=100, )  # posicion del titulo
ionograma.config(bg="#0A0A1A", fg="#FFFFFF")  # color de fondo y color de letra


botonera= Frame (raiz)                                            #margenes botonera
botonera.config(bg="white")
botonera.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.08,relwidth=0.09, relheight=0.7)

#BOTONES
boton = Button(botonera, text="SCAM",font=letra_b,height=4, width=17)
boton.pack()

boton2 = Button(botonera, text="Mediciones",font=letra_b,height=3, width=17)
boton2.pack()

boton3 = Button(botonera, text="Informacion",font=letra_b,height=3, width=17)
boton3.pack()

#contenedor = Frame(raiz)                                           #margenes donde va ir la matriz
#contenedor.config(bg="white")
#contenedor.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.8, relheight =0.8)

#Tamaño de la imagen
x = 1240
y = 680

#Crear canvas
canvas = Canvas(raiz, width = x, height = y, bg = "#ffffff")
canvas.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.8)

#Crear imagen
img = PhotoImage(width = x, height = y)
canvas.create_image((0, 0), image = img, state = "normal", anchor = NW)

#Imagen de prueba, dibujará cada pixel del tamaño x, y. si el pixel es múltiplo de 310 en "x" o de 170 en "y" lo pondrá en rojo , de lo contrario en azul
ionograma = ' '.join('{' + ' '.join(' #ff0000' if ((i%310==0) or (j%170==0)) else ' #0000ff' for i in range(x)) + '}' for j in range(y))

start_time = time.perf_counter()
#Poner la imagen
img.put(ionograma)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.perf_counter() - start_time))

raiz.mainloop()
```

Termina de dibujar la imagen en:

```
--- 0.7016952999983914 seconds ---
```

Y el resultado es:

[image: Ionograma prueba]

Si cuentas con todos los datos en una matriz fácilmente la podrías dibujar recorriendo cada elemento de la matriz en lugar de los `range()` que puse en la variable `ionograma`

Por cierto, si vas a utilizar matrices te recomendaría utilizar `numpy`, las listas nativas de python contienen otros datos que hacen que ocupe mucha memoria, al utilizar `numpy` harás tu proceso más rápido y eficiente.

Comment: grandeeee !! mcuhas gracias